# My Spring Boot contoller health check fails even though its the same as the other one

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is a controller that works

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/students")
public class StudentController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/health2")
    public String Health2() {
        return "Online!##@@@@"; // works!
    }

}
```

Now here is a controller that doesn't work

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/ws")
public class RecordingController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/health")
  public String foo() {
      return "Running";
  }
}
```

`GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/students/health2` <= "Online!##@@@@"

`GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ws/health` gives

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-04-03T17:26:01.369+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/v1/ws/health"
}
```

How do I fix it please? My imports all work

My expectation is that copying the same forms into another controller will work identically to the previous one

My actual result is that the second controller fails but I dont know why

I tried it also as `@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/ws")` but it still fails

I have restarted my server.

Edit: Solution

```
// package com.example.messagingstompwebsocket; // remove this
package hotjar.demo.student; // add this
```

Comment: Nothing is the startup logs about problems exposing the second controller? What are the packages of both controllers and the @SpringbootApplication class?

Comment: Boom. You got it. Thank you. Updating OP with the source of the problem and solution